# Definitive way to setup Docksal on Windows 11

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, xdebug, docksal

I love Docksal and it works great on my Ubuntu machine, however I now need to develop within Windows 11.

Is there a definitive (preferred) approach to installing and using Docksal on Windows 11? There are so many conflicting articles on the web.

Do we :

1. Use only WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 for instance?
2. Install Docker Desktop / Docker for Windows?
3. Use VirtualBox?

I'd prefer to use PhpStorm but may need to accept that VSCode is the easier option.

I need to use Xdebug from my IDE.

Comment: The Docksal documentation (https://docksal.io/installation/#windows) says: "Choose how you want to use Docker. VirtualBox: **Recommended.**; Faster, allows launching Vagrant alongside.

Comment: I did follow those instructions however when I run the docksal install - bash <(curl -fsSL https://get.docksal.io) the output of the script suggests installing and using Docker Desktop